ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2' while makemigrations on postgres DB
I cloned a github project on Django and i was following the instructions to execute the program.
I am new so, i went ahead and downloaded postgres and installed it.
at the make migrations step, this error was logged along with bunch of paths :-
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
i was following the steps given in the documentation file for this which are as follows :
"

Installing the Postgres and enabling it in the background
We will go to telusko\settings.py in the project folder
Around line 78, there's DATABASES dictionary, we will set the value for keys ('NAME', 'USER' & 'PASSWORD') to 'postgres'
Then we'll execute python3 manage.py makemigrations & python3 manage.py migrate
Finally, we will run the project by python3 manage.py runserver
"

i followed the steps, at the 3rd step, instead of 'postgre' as the password, i typed in the password asked at the installation process
BUT
at the 4th step when i run the
python3 manage.py makemigrations

this error is shown: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

i want this project somehow working till tomorrow so please help

Have you installed psycopg2? pip install psycopg2 or, as you are on Windows, pip install psycopg2-binary.

install postgres in pip
pip install postgres

